# Do we exactly need to invoke addSubview() to link a custom view file and the corresponding xib file?

Tags: ios

To link a xib file and the custom view one, do we need to invoke the `addSubview()` method?

We can link them like this:

```
let subView = NSBundle().loadNibNamed("customVIew", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

self.view.addSubview(subView)
```

Otherwise, as a static method, we can the same thing by this:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: self.className, bundle: nil)

let objects = nib.instantiate(withOwner: ownerOrNil, options: nil)

return objects.first as Self
```

Do they have any difference?  One uses `addSubview()` and the another doesn't use the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One uses `addSubview()` and the another doesn't use the method

And the second one, which never says `addSubview()`, never gets the view into the interface. But in the second case, what was the point of saying `return objects.first`? Very likely so that the *caller* could say `addSubview()`. Sooner or later, *someone* will probably say it, or the loading of the view will have been in vain. Why would you instantiate a view (which is what loading a nib does) if you didn't want to put that view into your interface?

Comment: Having said that, there are in fact reasons why you _might_ load a view without ever putting it into the interface. But those reasons are very rare indeed.

Comment: Note that the call to `addSubview` might not be in your code. In particular, if the nib file owner is a `UIViewController` and the File's Owner's `view` outlet is connected to a view in the nib, and the file owner (view controller) is later presented or made a child view controller, that will end up calling `addSubview` with the view controller's view.

Comment: Very very sorry.  You are absolutely right.  This is my tiny overlook.